80s or 90s anime movie about a warrior girl with a dragon-like-dinosaur pet who was given a magical necklace
I was 6 or 7 years old when I watched this anime. My dad bought the CD.
I think the genre is echi because there was a lot of gratuitous nudity.
Condensed version of events:

Warrior girl arrives at a new town hosting a parade
She gets attacked, fends off three goons
She ends up kidnapped in a castle dungeon with other women
Old man gives her a magical necklace
Her friend is tortured and killed by a sorcerer
She fights the sorcerer, who turns into a two-headed dragon that breaths blue fire and stakes
She dies, but the necklace resurrects her and her friend
They defeat the sorcerer (killing him) and rescue those trapped in the dungeon


Detailed version of events
A girl (she was blonde if I remember) just arrived at a town along with her dragon-like-dinosaur pet. She was wearing a bra-like top and underwear-like bottom (but it's armor). Her pet is bigger than her so she can ride on it (it can fly). There was some sort of parade in that town when she arrives. She was just walking down the sidewalk while people watched the parade. In that parade, there was an old fat guy who was like a king or something. He was riding on a wall-less litter (vehicle). He saw the blonde girl walking down the sidewalk. He then commands his servants/men to bring that girl to him. So three of his men followed the girl. 
The girl was heading to a bar/inn where she could eat and rest. She enters the bar/inn and headed to the bar section. She ordered something (I can't remember what she said). When the owner/bartender gave her her order, he then said something to her. Then the girl replied "I'm a warrior" while munching on her food.  They kept on having a conversation until those men came in and find her. The men try to persuade the girl to go with them, but the girl refuses. Then suddenly, one of the men slaps the girl's upper thighs and rubs them. The girl was so pissed she punched him. That man falls. The two other man attack the girl but she punches them too. One man gets up, pulls out a dagger and tries to injure the girl. However, when he turns around, a sword's tip was touching his nose. It was the girl's sword. She then said "Do you wanna die?". The man was sacred so he fled the area along with his subordinates.  
She was kidnapped when she tried to attack the fat king-like guy.  When she awoke, she was in a dungeon cell with some other women. 
Someone told her to meet an old guy at the deepest end of the cell. When she went there she saw an old skinny man sitting at the end of the cell (more like a cave because there was a water flowing sound).  He offers the girl to sit in front of him. She sat down and the old man showed the girl an old box.
He then opens the box and shows the girl what was inside. It was a necklace/ collar with a pendant in the middle. The necklace was gold and the pendant, I think, was red.
The girl said that it's beautiful. The old man said that the necklace has magic powers. He then gives it to the girl. The girl thanked the old man.
The girl was in a castle. Going at the upper most floor where her friend (a guy) is being held as hostage (I think). A sorcerer tortures the guy. when the girl was almost at the top, her friend died. the sorcerer threw him in a hole. 
The girl attacks the sorcerer but he dodges it (I think). The sorcerer then transformed into a two headed dragon where one head breaths blue fire while the other head spits out a long wooden steak. 
The girl was stabbed at the thigh with the steak. The sorcerer combined the blue fire and the steaks together and attacked the girl at her chest. 
The girl was hit. there was a big hole in her chest. So many blood came out. She said something in her thoughts. Then she dies. 
suddenly, her necklace (the pendant) was glowing brightly. Her wounds are glowing as well. The necklace revive the girl along with her friend. 
The sorcerer became a giant rock-like person. The girl and her friend rides on her dragon then flew up high above the clouds. They're thinking of a way on how to destroy the sorcerer.
The sorcerer was killed. the girl and her friend went back to lower ground to save the other women who were kidnapped by that fat king-like guy. 
The girl was waving to the other women while she and her friend was riding on the dragon-like-dinosaur.

this really needs to be condensed down...

Shot in the dark - Dragons + nudity = Heavy Metal ?

do you mean stake ? instead of steak, beefsteak

Right. Thank you

You're looking for the anime OVA Legend of Lemnear from 1989.

The story focuses around the title character, Lemnear, who according to prophecy is the Champion of Silver. She seeks revenge on the evil wizard Gardein and the master he serves, attempting to avenge the slaughter of her people. (This, and several other aspects of design and nature, may connect her to the character of the Taarakian Taarna in Heavy Metal, including her sword, hair color, and mode of transportation.)

Everything you (meticulously) mentioned is there, including the final fight with the sorcerer (he turns into a two-headed dragon that breathes blue fire and stakes; she's hurt but her pendant cures her; he turns into a rock demon and is eventually defeated and they escape on her pet flying dinosaur). The entire thing is currently available here, and here's a clip (with that first part you described: Lemnear arriving at a town during a parade, fighting the fat king's men in a bar etc.):



